# Javascript/node.js sending data between server and client

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, client

I am writing a recipe search engine and i am stuck at sending data between client and server as i didn't work with backend before (i am a beginner in coding).
On the client side i ask user to choose category which he wants the recipe for (e.g chicken).
 Then the choice is saved in variable and that is being send to the server. That's all working right. 
Then on the server i want to pass the category to API Call, make the Call and send the data back to the client, how do i do that ?
Here's some code: 
CLIENT-SIDE:

```
function getRecipes(category){
    const categorySearch = category.alt;
    let data = {
        categoryChoice: categorySearch
    }
    let options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
    const promise = fetch('/data', options);
    promise.then(response => {
        if(!response.ok){
            console.error(response)
        } else {
            return response.json();
        }
    }).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
}
```

SERVER-SIDE

```
app.post('/data', async (request, response) => {
    const data = await request.body;
    const gotData = data.categoryChoice;
    const category = gotData;
    console.log(category);
    response.json(category);
    return category
})

app.get('/data', async (request, response) => {
    const cat = await category;
    const url = `https://edamam-recipe-search.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=${cat}&from=0&to=100`
    const fetch_response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await fetch_response.json();
    response.json(json);
})
```

app.get doesn't logs or gives me anything so i don't think it even works

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
app.get('/data', async (request, response) => {
    const cat = await category;
    const url = `https://edamam-recipe-search.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=${cat}&from=0&to=100`
    fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
        response.json(json);
    });
})
```

Comment: No, still nothing :( Probably i will also need another fetch on the client side to get data from api call in the server

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use only one 'post' method for that(on both frontend and backend). Assuming that your code is correct, it should be something like that:

```
app.post('/data', async (request, response) => {
    const data = request.body;
    const category = data.categoryChoice;
    console.log(category);
    const url = `https://edamam-recipe-search.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=${category}&from=0&to=100`
    const fetch_response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await fetch_response.json();
    response.json(json);
})
```

Comment: I am getting this error : ```recipes.js:126 POST http://localhost:3100/data 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: Have you changed method on client side to 'GET'?

Comment: Yes but then i can't send body with the category to the server. Anyway i've manage to solve. I have moved API call to app.post part and that worked :)